# Dynamically created p element not appended to dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, dom, append, element

By some reason the p element in the function below isn't created (and/or appended to the div). If I append it to '#listOfListObjects' as with the div, it works, but I want it inside the div.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('#addListObjectSubmit').click(function (e) {

        var listObjectName = $('#m_newListObject').val();

        if((listObjectName == null) || (listObjectName == '')) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var listDiv = 'listDiv' + i;

            $('<div>', {
                class: 'listObjectShow',
                id: listDiv
            }).appendTo('#listOfListObjects');

            $('<p>', {
                class: 'listObjectShow',
                text: listObjectName,
                id: 'listObject' + i
            }).appendTo(listDiv);
        }

        i += 1;

        e.preventdefault();
    });
```

Comment: for what I see without testing, I think you miss the `#` in the selector, so  should be `.appendTo("#" + listDiv);` imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

`var listDiv = 'listDiv' + i;`

to

`var listDiv = '#listDiv' + i;`

or

```
$('<div>', {
    class: 'listObjectShow',
    id: listDiv
}).appendTo('#listOfListObjects');

$('<p>', {
    class: 'listObjectShow',
    text: listObjectName,
    id: 'listObject' + i
 }).appendTo(listDiv);
```

To

```
$('<div>', {
     class: 'listObjectShow',
     id: listDiv
 }).appendTo('#listOfListObjects');

 $('<p>', {
     class: 'listObjectShow',
     text: listObjectName,
     id: 'listObject' + i
 }).appendTo('#' + listDiv);
```

Comment: The first option didn't work, however "appendTo('#' + listDiv)" did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`text` is not a property of the `<p>` element.

You should change:

```
$('<p>', {
    class: 'listObjectShow',
    text: listObjectName,
    id: 'listObject' + i
}).appendTo(listDiv);
```

to

```
$('<p>', {
    class: 'listObjectShow',
    id: 'listObject' + i
}).text(listObjectName).appendTo(listDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

My most loved way for such things is this

```
var $div = $('<div>', {
               class : 'listObjectShow',
               id    : listDiv
           }).appendTo('#listOfListObjects');

$('<p>', {
    class : 'listObjectShow',
    id    : 'listObject' + i
}).text(listObjectName).appendTo( $div );
```

no problems with selectors, ids etc... just a simple reference to the new div is used